# how to land www.example.com/subfolder on /index.asp not /index.html

Tags: iis, asp, seo

In attempt to answer my question I did:

1. read Miscrosoft "[using virtual directories](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/8c110149-8060-4dd7-9bdb-e262c21483dd.mspx?mfr=true)"
2. read over a dozen + posts on stackoverflow / codingforum / dmxzone  without a clear answer
            for my reading I searched terms:  "virtual folder" , subfolder redirect, redirect subfolder to .asp
3. While I learned some new terms, I'm not certain I'll even be using the correct language to ask this question.
4. In attempt to migrate current webpage that is structred

   example.com/[files 1-30].asp

QUESTION:

How do I make a browser pointed to :

example.com/products/widget/

load like `example.com/products/widget/index.asp`

without an `/index.html` in the file folder (no that .html is not an error see my trial and error below)?

- Reasoning, I would like to structure for organization / growth / seo

  - - example.com/products/widget/
  - - example.com/products/super-widget/
  - - example.com/other-product/not-so-super-widget
- Presently, the site is hosted on Windows Server 2003 Microsoft-IIS/6.0
- All of the page files are .asp

When I've experimented by pointing a browser to

example.com/products/widget/index.asp`
**I have success**

`example.com/products/widget/`
**I get "virtual directory not accessible"**

when I tried 
`example.com/products/widget/index.html`
**I have success**

And then when I tried
`example.com/products/widget/`
**I have success**

Thanks,
Casey

Answer (score 1):

Modify the default document for your web site to be `index.asp` in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

On the windows server 2003,

- open the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager;
- right click on the site you would like to change the default document (if you only have one it would be the Default Web Site);
- click on the properties menu;
- Select the Tab Documents;
- Enable default document (if its not already);
- add the index.asp and move it to the top.

Now index.asp will be your default document and you will be able to type example.com/products/widget/ and IIS will call index.asp

This will work for every foldre you have on the default web site

cheers

PC